# c# Reset Cancellation token

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, cancellation

I have some code I want to run until I request cancellation.

```
              Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        GetFeedbackTask();
                    }
                }, token);
```

I then execute this method `token.Cancel()`.  This cancels the task as expected and my while loop as expected.  The problem is when I try to run the Task again after I cancel the `token.IsCancellationRequested` property is still `true`.  What sets the property back to `false`? Do I need to `Dispose` the token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't ever set a `CancellationToken` from a cancelled state back into a non-cancelled state.

Likewise, the `Task` that you've created to do work will have ended; it's not just going to sit there waiting once the token is cancelled.  The `while`loop will have ended, and as there is no more code the task will be completed.

If you want to re-start the work after having cancelled it *start a new worker* and *create a new cancellation token*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a new `CancellationTokenSource` - there is no way to reset this once you set it.

```
token.Dispose(); // Clean up old token source....
token= new CancellationTokenSource(); // "Reset" the cancellation token source...
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        GetFeedbackTask();
    }
}, token);
```